# Get Value of Name Tag from EC2 instances using jq

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jq

I am trying to get the values of the `Name` tag of AWS EC2 instances using jq.

`aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | .Tags[] | select (.Key == "Name")'`

But I am getting this error:

```
jq: error: Name/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.Reservations[].Instances[] | .Tags[] | select (.Key == Name)
jq: 1 compile error
```

This is the json I'm trying to process:

```
{
    "Reservations": [{
        "Instances": [{
            "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
            "ImageId": "ami-00c3c949f325a4149",
            "InstanceId": "i-0c17052ee1c7113e5",
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "Tags": [{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "bastion001"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "environment",
                    "Value": "stg-us-east"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

How can I get the value of the `Name` tag from EC2 instances?

Comment: Here is a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBBbsIwELz3FZZPRSKRTRIglThwjKh6qKpeEKq2ZgmusFFjB1G1eXvqJFXUJAh88e7OzI49H59l6T@jwewEVh61WW/8RBsLWqCryQ/xXyBtKoMHFJbc@yv8IosFoU@gkI7K8vuOuEP/r6EPZN2Ma6hd2Z3X2FLJR8i12Cd6i2dHYOMuIVGQYrJ1CAUlPcZEIOIw3gWTCEIexrTP/zNrJE4g@IxFE0QuZpwHGPUFy0zspXV/yzOsJOf59G0a9llVDsPnt7ALpdLWmYwvU17hkNcG72CqlBjjdMAshuLrjqhPMjtqhdreNDY29XLjofO/4NyZbNquaEp3Fb8 "jq – Try It Online") with your filter and json.  It looks ok as a start.  You can get the name by adding `| .Value`.  [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s advice is best if you see errors like yours.

Comment: OK awesome! Thanks for that, I will try it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need extra tools like `jq` to query the output. AWS CLI has JMESPath 
 built-in to help you do that.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[?Key == `Name`].Value'
```

Comment: true but that's not the question

Comment: Is it best to have one external call to AWS and use jq a few times on the saved response or call AWS for each tag value you want?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this, this will get what you want from ec2 in a comma separated list

```
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] \ | ((.Tags // empty) | from_entries) as $tags | [($tags.Name), ($tags.environment), .ImageId, .InstanceId, .AmiLaunchIndex] | @csv'
```

The `.Tags // empty` will ignore those with tags that do not exist if you are wondering.

Hope this helps, it Is correct you do not need jq to get these details, but this is how you do it with :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the jq command-line expression shown in the Q and the error message. I would suggest that, at least until you have sorted things out, you put your jq program in a file, and invoke jq with the -f command-line option.